# Code to add a host header to an IIS Website

Tags: c#, iis-7, active-directory

I have a single site that has many names. I want to be able to programatically add a new host header record to IIS to allow it to recognize another name. Specifically, what is the code (preferably in C#) to add a new host header to a given site?

Comment: Does the code below not answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AddHostHeader(1, "127.0.0.1", 8080, "fred");
    AddHostHeader(1, null, 8081, null);
}

static void AddHostHeader(int? websiteID, string ipAddress, int? port, string hostname)
{
    using (var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/w3svc/" + websiteID.ToString()))
    {
        var bindings = directoryEntry.Properties["ServerBindings"];
        var header = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", ipAddress, port, hostname);

        if (bindings.Contains(header))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Host Header already exists!");

        bindings.Add(header);
        directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Impersonate or use Windows Identity Object